# How to override an android style's private attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I am trying to find a way to override a non-public attribute of an android style, more specifically an atttribute named `itemColor` of the `Widget.FragmentBreadCrumbs` style. This style affects the text color of the breadcumb in a `PreferenceActivity` when a preference fragment is being displayed on the right pane for large screens. It is used by the class [FragmentBreadCrumbs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentBreadCrumbs.html).

My application uses a custom theme that extends `Theme.Holo.Light` and the theme breaks on API 23 so I am trying to find a workaround.

The aforementioned style sets a default value to `itemColor` of `@null` which is not overridden in the Holo theme while for example it is set to a valid value for the Material theme. As a result the title of the breadcrumb is not visible (see [screenshot for API 19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAfEU.png) and [screenshot for API 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2w9b.png))

I guess what I am trying to do is to find a way that could change a private value of a theme similar to the way reflection can be used to modify the private field's value of a class. Alternatively the [ContextThemeWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html) seems to be promising but I simple don't get how can I use it or even if it is applicable in my situtation.

What I need is that after `FragmentBreadCrumbs` class executes its constructor below the `mTextColor` attribute to not be `@null` (which I am guessing is `0`) as is set by the Android theme configuration but to have a valid color value.

Do you think this is possible?

```
public FragmentBreadCrumbs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.FragmentBreadCrumbs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    mGravity = a.getInt(com.android.internal.R.styleable.FragmentBreadCrumbs_gravity,
            DEFAULT_GRAVITY);

    mLayoutResId = a.getResourceId(
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.FragmentBreadCrumbs_itemLayout,
            com.android.internal.R.layout.fragment_bread_crumb_item);

    /* This is the value needed to be overridden */
    mTextColor = a.getColor(
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.FragmentBreadCrumbs_itemColor,
            0);

    a.recycle();
}
```

Comment: Do you have the FragmentBreadCrumbs object in your code? (Can you get an instance of it?) @c.s.

Comment: @NirDuan No. I don't know how to get one. This class is instantiated by an `<include>` statement inside the xml layout file used by the `PreferenceActivity`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the toolchain will report an error if you try to use `android:itemColor` because this does not correspond to a public attribute name, so you cannot even make a style with this attribute.

The only thing I can think of is to change the text color via reflection just after the views have been constructed(/inflated). You would want to do this as early as possible, before the first time `updateCrumbs()` is run inside of `FragmentBreadCrumbs`. Perhaps you can override `onCreate()` of `PreferenceActivity` or `onCreateView()` of `PreferenceFragment` (whichever is applicable here) and do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentBreadCrumbs fbc = (FragmentBreadCrumbs) findViewById(...);
    int color = ...;
    FragmentBreadCrumbsUtils.setTextColor(fbc, color);
}


public class FragmentBreadCrumbsUtils {

    private static final Field FRAGMENT_BREAD_CRUMBS_TEXT_COLOR = findField();
    private static Field findField() {
        try {
            Field f = FragmentBreadCrumbs.class.getDeclaredField("mTextColor");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            return f;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // don't fail for any reason, just log it
            Log.e("FragmentBreadCrumbsUtils",
                "Couldn't find mTextColor field in FragmentBreadCrumbs",
                t);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void setTextColor(FragmentBreadCrumbs fbc, int color) {
        if (FRAGMENT_BREAD_CRUMBS_TEXT_COLOR == null) {
            return; // can't do anything, we don't have the field
        }

        try {
            FRAGMENT_BREAD_CRUMBS_TEXT_COLOR.set(fbc, color);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // don't fail for any reason, just log it
            Log.e("FragmentBreadCrumbsUtils",
                "Couldn't set mTextColor field in FragmentBreadCrumbs",
                t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `onCreate()` is already too late. However your post and and the initial comment helped me to find the answer. I can override the `findViewById()` to find the instance before it is used by `PreferenceActivity`. If you don't mind adding this to your answer I will accept it otherwise I will answer my own question. Thanks for the help

Comment: @c.s. Overriding `findViewbyId()` feels uncomfortable to my taste (but then again, so does reflection trickery). Whatever works I guess, that's just how Android is sometimes.

Comment: I completely agree. Reflection was not even in my list until after I have made the question. I have mentioned it in the text only as an example of what I am trying to do which was to override the style's private attribute. However I have pretty much exhausted any other options before making the question, (to be honest I did not expect any answer that would work).  But it is as you said, this is how Android is sometimes